# Using Google Closure Library for Google DART?

Tags: google-closure, dart

How can the Google Closure UI Library be used with Google DART?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart has no facility for using JavaScript libraries.  This is by design as Dart is intended to target both the Dart VM and Dart translated to JS.  It is possible to workaround this to some extent by using message passing between iFrames and web workers.

Comment: But doesn't Dart use some features of Closure? Or am I confusing Closure and Closure Library?

Comment: It uses the Closure compiler to optimise the Javascript that it generates, but the UI code is entirely Dart's own.

Comment: There are two compilers for Dart, however neither uses the Closure compiler. Perhaps they use techniques shared by Closure, but they are custom Dart -> JavaScript compilers.

Comment: @Seth, Dartc does use Closure Compiler for its optimized output unless something changed recently.

Answer (score 1):

Although at present, you can't use the closure libraries directly, some effort is underway to port some of the more useful libraries, for example, the crypto libraries are here: http://code.google.com/p/dart-crypto-lib/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) to use any Js library. Have a look at [Using JavaScript from Dart: The js Library](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) to know how to use it.